# How to import custom fonts (as ttf) to illustrator?

Tags: fonts, adobe-illustrator

How can we import new fonts like [Google Roboto](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/roboto)  into Adobe Illustrator CS 6?

Answer (score 2):

You do not import fonts into a program;  you import them into the operating system, presumably Windows in your case.  The font you mention is available as a TTF (TrueType) download.  Once you have the TTF files, you would add it, for example in Windows 7, by right-clicking the font (wherever you've downloaded the TTF file(s) and choosing Install.

You can also add fonts by copying them to the Fonts folder, but there are reports that this approach doesn't always work.

Once the fonts are added in Windows, they are available in -all- programs.